# Is it ok that my laundry drain trap is tilted?

Tags: plumbing, drain, p-trap

I'm working on the drain for my laundry, and there isn't enough space to fit a vertical drain pipe above the P trap.+

Is the vertical pipe coming in being slightly offset going to be an issue with the inspector? (*The P trap itself is level*).

[image]

Comment: It's hard to understand your question with the picture. How is it that the vertical pipe coming in is slightly offset? Does the picture show that? And you state that the P trap itself is level, but it certainly does not look level in your picture...

Comment: I am concerned about the the 90 degree turn just under the discharge inlet of the laundry box. Normally there is a straight run down of 12 to 18 into the Ptrap and then the plumbing make its turns. My concern is that the force of the discharge from the washing machine hose will be so strong that i will hit the 90 elbow and blow back up and out of the box. Maybe !

Comment: Standpipes must be 18-30" in length. **The entire drain needs to be lowered.**

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the hole drilled on the outlet side of the p-trap needs to be enlarged so the hub of the fitting can slip in, thus leveling the p-trap, thus keeping it from sticking out of the wall, however, ideally, and by most codes, there needs to be a larger drop directly from the installed washerbox, because  as piped, when the washer drains, water will shoot right back out of the opening.  The y fitting in the stack where this drain connects, needs to be lower, and you can eliminate some couplings in the lateral, by feeding your piping from the end of the wall.

Comment: also, there needs to be an 18" drop from the washer box, and then the p-trap goes there, not arouns the corner.  If there is space to move the washer box to the left, that should give you more room for the trap.  it may help next time, to have the plumbing rough-in done BEFORE the wiring is done.